# How do I update a progress bar OnSelectedIndexChanged?

Tags: .net-2.0, c#-2.0

I am developing a Windows application using .NET (C#) and I have a `DropDownList` with some list items. On the event `OnSelectedIndexChanged` I need to display a progess bar, which should disappear after retrieving some data.

I'm trying this way:

```
for (int i = progressBar1.Minimum; i <= progressBar1.Maximum; i++)
{
    progressBar1.PerformStep();
}
panel1.Visible = false;
```

where my progress bar is placed in `panel1`, but I get the progress bar when I initially load my application. After that whenever the item is changed the progress bar is not visible.
I need the solution asap...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try `panel1.Visible = true;` at the start of your on selected index changed event of the combo box.

Comment: initially it is set to true anly .but i am not getting the progressbar on selected index changed

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the code that would make the Panel visible again and you would also need to reset the ProgressBar before updating it again by changing the Value property to zero.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(...)
{  
    progressBar1.Value=progressBar1.Minimum;
    panel1.Visible = true;
    for (int i = progressBar1.Minimum; i <= progressBar1.Maximum; i++) 
    { 
    progressBar1.PerformStep(); 
    } 
    panel1.Visible = false
}
```

This should make the panel1 visible, however, I'm not sure what you mean by:

> "and should disappear after retrieving
>   some data"

and if the solution of filling the progress bar solves it.